# How To Replace Multi Chars In One String

Tags: javascript

I have this string : `var mstr = "Thanks a lot :) :D";`

and I want to replace `:)` and `:D` to it's `<img>`

I have tried this :

```
$(".messagespackage").children().each(function () {
$(this).html( $(this).html().replace(new RegExp(':)','g'),'<img src="smile.png">','g') );
});
```

But it didn't replace anymore !
How can I do that ,Please ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want multiple replace.

```
String.prototype.allReplace = function(obj) {
    var retStr = this;
    for (var x in obj) {
        retStr = retStr.replace(new RegExp(x, 'g'), obj[x]);
    }
    return retStr;
};

console.log('aabbaabbcc'.allReplace({'a': 'h', 'b': 'o'}));
// console.log 'hhoohhoocc';
```